# How to create additional options for a specific block

Tags: reactjs, block, wordpress-gutenberg

I created a plugin that has a Gutenberg block created with React, my block consists of the following files (edit.js, save.js, index.js, block.json, style.scss, editor.scss). This plugin has many options already in the free version, but I would like to implement other paid options. These extensions can be purchased individually according to your needs. My problem is this, how do I create plugins that add additional controls in the free plugin block? I was told that in the free block I cannot hide paid options, I have to add them separately. Any advice would be appreciated, thanks.

I tried hiding the paid options directly in the free block, and activating them only if the license is valid, this works, but from what I was told it is not allowed. I'm also not sure it's the most optimal method. I would like to be able to create plugins that when activated add (pro) options to the free block.

Answer (score 0):

If your plugin was uploaded for review on the WordPress plugin directory they gave the advice to remove the hidden paid features, I would do that as the plugin directory is open source (ref [Planning, Submitting, and Maintaining Plugins](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-org/planning-submitting-and-maintaining-plugins/)). In your initial 1.0 release, promote the paid version with a non-intrusive link to your other site where a license is obtained to install the "pro" version - also see how see other like well known plugins like [Yoast](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-seo/) and [Jetpack](https://wordpress.org/plugins/jetpack/) upsell and review the code inside their plugins.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help, however I solved it by adding the function to see if the additional plugin (extension) is installed and active, then the main plugin shows the additional functions.